# Plotting power function in python but graph is blank

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, numbers

[Image has the error that I have and it does not show any error with my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4ixC.png)I am trying to plot the graph of a function I=t^n such that after  gap of every 30 steps, the value of n becomes n/2 where initially n=4.
There is no error on running the code but I am not getting any graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

n=4
for t in range (1,193):
       I=t**n
       if(t%30==0):
           n=n/2

plt.plot(t,I,'r')

plt.xticks([0, 10, 41, 71, 101, 132, 163],
          ["Jan","Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July"])
plt.xlabel('Months')
plt.ylabel('Cases')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting an error? With python3.8.5 I am getting a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'int' and 'float'`

Comment: @user2640045 hey no, I am not getting any error. I have uploaded the page actually. Kindly check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your code, I think you want to store the values from the `for`-loop in a list and plot that list. Instead of taking the last value of `t` and `I` in this line:

```py
plt.plot(t,I,'r')
```

Try creating a list to put the value from `I` into and give that list to the `plt.plot` function.

This should work:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

n = 4
data = [] # Create a list for the data to be appended to
for t in range (1, 193):
    I = t**n
    if (t % 30 == 0):
        n /= 2
    data.append(I) # Append the data to the list

plt.plot(data, 'r') # Plot the data from the list

plt.xticks([0, 10, 41, 71, 101, 132, 163],
          ["Jan","Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July"])
plt.xlabel('Months')
plt.ylabel('Cases')

plt.show()
```

This should give the following plot:

[image: Plotted data]

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot but actually 'n' is not always supposed to be int. I want the value of n to go on like 4,2,1,1/2,1/4... until the entire range is covered

Comment: Also I think it will be t**n and not t^n

Comment: @Additi.P I have updated the answer to answer your updated question

Comment: Thanks a lot! got the exact graph I wanted in semi log scale thanks a lot

Comment: I did upvote but it does  not count my upvotes since I have less than 15 reputations

Comment: @Additi.P Since you're new to StackOverflow, you indeed do not have enough reputation to cast an upvote that will increase the vote counter. However, since you are the one that asked the question, you can accept the answer as a valid answer to the question, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), this will make it easier for future people on SO find a solution to their problems.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem with your code is `^` operator.
In *Python* it is **XOR** operator, whereas as I suppose that you actually
want the **power** operator (`**`).

Another flaw in your code is that when you want to create a plot, you have to
assemble both *x* and *y* values and then call *plt.plot* passing both lists.

But you compute respective values in your loop and substitute them under
"single" variables (not append to arrays).

Yet another point to correct is that *t* (an array holding *x* values) can
be generated in one go as a *Numpy* array (*t = np.arange(...)*) and then
generate *I* (as a **list**), based on the current value from *t* and *n*.

So change your code to:

```
import numpy as np

n = 4
t = np.arange(1, 194)
I = []
for tt in t:
    I.append(tt ** n)
    if (tt % 30 == 0):
        n /= 2
plt.plot(t, I, 'r')
```

The rest of code - as in your post.

If the array holding *x* values contained consecutive values starting
from *0*, you could call *plt.plot(I, 'r')* omitting *t*.
But since *t* starts from *1*, I couldn't do it (there would be
a "shift by 1" on the *x* axis).

## Edit

To get the picture in semi log scale, as you wrote in one of comments,
run:

```
plt.semilogy(t, I, 'r')
```

instead of `plt.plot(...)`.